# Supervisord unable to shutdown fcgi processes

Tags: bash, django, fastcgi, supervisord, fcgi

I've managed to set up supervisord with fastcgi on a django project of mine, the problem is that when I make mi program stop, the server keeps running somehow, and my page keeps online.

Here is my supervisord program directive:

```
[program:helloworld]
command=/var/www/django-projects/helloworld/run
```

Here is my "run" script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /var/www/django-projects/helloworld/venv/bin/activate;
/var/www/django-projects/helloworld/manage.py runfcgi \
     daemonize=false \
     host=127.0.0.1 \
     port=8000;
```

All I want is a way to stop/start/restart this django project using supervisord, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try running socketed:

```
/var/www/django-projects/helloworld/manage.py runfcgi \
         daemonize=false \
         outlog=/desired/path/log/django-fcgi.log \
         socket=/desired/path/var/run/django-run.socket \
         pidfile=/desired/path/var/run/django.pid
```